# Image upload not working in android webview

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, webview

I have a webapp made on rails where users can signup and upload photos , i have converted this into an android app using WebView, everything works fine but when i click on the select photo button nothings happen, i searched about it but didn't find the issue.

In my android manifest file i have added some permissions but this doesn't solves anything:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access the android mobile phone's gallery with the code by which you have developed the website. The code you have written is for the accessing them from the pc, not mobile phones.

And you cannot be able to access the gallery of the android phone and get the selected image in the web view. If you know the advance part of coding if your bootstrap for the mobile is activated then use the intent of android.

You can try adding the code to your application to access the gallery. This might or might not work. This code is to get an image when the button is clicked in android phone and not for the web view. You have to **manipulate the code** to get the image.

First, you have to launch the Gallery App using the built-in Intents. After that, on your onActivityResult(), get the path of the selected image and load your image into your ImageView.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AndroidSelectImage extends Activity {

 TextView textTargetUri;
 ImageView targetImage;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);
     textTargetUri = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targeturi);
     targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

     buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }});
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
 Uri targetUri = data.getData();
 textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
 Bitmap bitmap;
 try {
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
  targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
}
}
```

Comment: i am new to android, i thought webview is same like android browser, and my webapp used to work fine on android browsers, after clicking the button it used to give me options to choose image from gallery or file manager

Comment: No, it is not same as the android browser. The browser itself is huge application to build in which all these necessary and small features are added. The browser is of 100+MB. And the Web view is less than 1MB when you build the.apk file of the application. Now, you can see  that how the browser is completely different from the simple Web view. You have add the features you want in the application.